# Is this 'as' an object: "as he called it"?

Tags: relative-pronouns

> "Hagrid," said Harry, panting a bit as he ran to keep up, "did you say
>   there are dragons at Gringotts?"
>   "Well, so they say," said Hagrid.
>   "Crikey, I'd like a dragon."
>   "You'd like one?"
>   "Wanted one ever since I was a kid –– here we go."
>   They had reached the station. There was a train to London in five minutes' 
>   time. Hagrid, who didn't understand "Muggle money," **as** he called it, gave the 
>   bills to Harry so he could buy their tickets.
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is ‘as’ a pronoun and direct object of ‘called’?

Comment: Wow. This one's beyond me. Within the clause it does function syntactically like a relative pronoun, doesn't it?--but with adverbial force. *[As] he called it _* ← *He called it [thus]*. Perhaps this is one for @snailboat.

Comment: @StoneyB, you've told exactly what I'm guessing. (1) Consulting my Korean English grammar book, 'as' is a similar relative; (2) but when I interpret it in my own tongue, it slides into like an adverbial.

Comment: @StoneyB: I can't see how it *functions syntactically **as** a relative pronoun*. You could perhaps call it "adverbial", but I'd say it's OED ***conjunction*** usage definition: *In a subordinate clause which expresses the manner, degree, time, place, reason, purpose, or result, of the main clause*. As ever, I think there's a law of diminishing returns when it comes to classifying things like this.

Comment: @FumbleFingers *As* behaves exactly like *which*. The underlying clause is something like *He called it* [*that/in that manner*]. The bracketed phrase has anaphoric reference to *Muggle Money*. *As* substitutes for [*in that manner*], just as *which* would substitute for [*that*], and moves to the front.

Comment: @StoneyB: Sure, you can "loosely" replace ***as*** with ***which, so, thus,*** etc. in this construction. But given there's already an *actual* pronoun ***it*** in there, I don't really see how ***as*** can be another one. And to me, it feels more like a conjunction than an adverb. Effectively, it's embedding ***he called** [the thing he didn't understand] **Muggle money*** into the existing noun phrase ***Muggle money***. That's only my opinion, ***as*** you know. (In which sentence I can swap the words before/after the comma, and/or delete ***as*** completely, so it's not really doing much).

Comment: @FumbleFingers *Call* is bitransitive. It takes 2 complements: the entity named, your *thing he didn't understand*, which is not explicit here but is what *it* refers to, and the name or attribute it is given, *"Muggle Money"*, which is what *as* (or *which*) refers to.

Comment: @StoneyB: Gotcha. Okay, perhaps it really could be best described as a pronoun then. But I think I'll leave it at that, because I really don't see this kind of "naming of parts" as particularly enlightening.

Comment: Might this question be well received on [ELU](http://english.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @Tyler: I suppose it *might* be interesting if someone were to make out a case for saying that ***as*** here is somehow syntactically distinct from, say, [*as it were*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63584/), *as we know*, etc. But as I keep saying, I think it's a bit of a sterile debate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The words *how* and *as* can function as **adverbial relative pronouns** with verbs like *call*.

---

The verb *call* can be used in different ways:

1. With an **object complement** denoting the name you assign:

   > He called her *his mistress*.
2. With an **adverbial constituent of manner** denoting *how* you call something, often similar to assigning a name:

   > Her called her *by her last name*.

The words *how* and *as* (similar to the adverbial phrase *the way [that]*) can replace the adverbial phrase and function as adverbial relative pronouns, just like *where*:

> He is *here*. (adverb / adverbial demonstrative pronoun of *place*)
>
> *Where* is he? (adverbial interrogative pronoun)
>
> Mordor is *where* the shadows lie. (adverbial relative pronoun, defining relative clause)
>
> He is in Mordor, *where* the shadows lie. (adverbial relative pronoun, non-defining)

With *so/how/as*:

> *So* is Gondor. (adverb / adverbial demonstrative pronoun of *manner*)
>
> How is Gondor?  (adverbial interrogative pronoun)
>
> Gondor is *how* I imagined it. (adverbial relative pronoun, defining)
>
> Gondor is *as* it should be. (adverbial relative pronoun, defining)
>
> She opposes Sauron, *as* she should do. (adverbial relative pronoun, non-defining)

With verbs meaning "address or assign a name to":

> They named Mordor *so* because of its dark shadows: *mor* means "dark", *dor* "land".
>
> They **called** it *thus*. (adverb / adverbial demonstrative pronoun of *manner*)
>
> ?They **called** Mordor *so*.
>
> ?*How* would you **call** a land like Mordor but in present-day Asia?
>
> ?That's not *as* they **called** it in the Silmarillion. (adverbial relative pronoun, defining)
>
> Mordor, or 'the land where the shadows lie', *as* they **called** it, was well defended. (non-defining)

With the word *call*, the construction with an object complement (1) is common and always possible. The construction with an adverbial constituent (2), however, is only common with normal adverbial phrases, with the adverbial demonstrative pronoun *thus*, and with *as* used as an adverbial relative pronoun introducing a *non-defining* relative clause, as in the last example and also in your example. I don't have an explanation for this: language is fickle.

Because object complements (1) and adverbial phrases (2) are often interchangeable with verbs like *call*, they tend to blur together sometimes. In non-standard English, you will even find *as* used as a simple subject or object relative pronoun:

> %The critter *as* did this was a big one. ("The critter that did this was a big one.")

Comment: +1 Good to see me and Listenever weren't just making it up.

Comment: @StoneyB: Haha, thanks. It's interesting how *so* and *that* can be interchangeable even with *do*: in *she did so / she did that*, the manner in which she acts can be semantically/referentially identical to the thing she acts upon. This reminds me of how *-ion* and all other kinds of nouns of action can also mean both the *act itself* and the *result of the act* or something else related to the act (mainly, but not only, when used as a semantic *theme*?): *the selection of wines took all day* v. *we have a large selection of wines*.